# Are there any wrappers/frameworks/libraries for Quartz 2D

Tags: quartz-graphics

Does anyone know of any wrappers/frameworks/libraries for Quartz2d (iOS deployment) which would make it easier/faster to do some of the more repetitive stuff like drawing circles, rectangles, translating stuff around the "canvas" etc etc.

In my childlike utopian dream world, I'm imagining something like [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/)

I've been googling, but not managed to hit the right search string if something does exist.